# ApplicationUser custom fields - Determining who can edit model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have added a isStudent field to my ApplicationUser model, self explanatory. It determines whether a user is a student or not.

I then have a model called Announcement which has an application user linked to it:

```
namespace CloserAgainFour.Models
{
public class Announcement
{
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }
    public string AnnouncementContent { get; set; }
    public bool Seen { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and a comment model which can comment on the announcement.

```
 namespace CloserAgainFour.Models
{
 public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }

    public virtual Announcement Announcement { get; set; }
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }
}
}
```

how could determine in the controller of announcement that only isStudent = false; can post announcements

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your view is using the Comment model, you test the value of model.Announcement.User.isStudent to conditionally display the form field for making a comment.

```
@if (Model.Announcement.User.isStudent)
{
    [whatever comment form field you want]
}
```